# linear transformation of real symmetric square positive semi-definite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I am trying to find properties or constraints on a $(p \times n) $matrix $U$ such that upon left multiplying a real symmetric square positive semi-definite matrix $V$ with $U$ the resulting matrix $W$ of dimensions $(p \times n) $ is still real positive semi-definite matrix.
In other words i am trying to establish that there is $U$ such that
$$W = U V$$
where $W$ and $V$ are real positive semi-definite matrices.

If $W=V$ then obviously $U=I$ fits the equation.

I have a suspicion that this should be possible as by definition of real symmetric positive semi-definite matrix, $V$  should have non-negative eigenvalues, which implies that it should have a right inverse which I suspect would also be positive semi-definite matrix, so if $W$ (some positive semi-definite matrix) is multiplied with the right inverse we should be able to compute $U$.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**edit**
I suspect if my reasoning about computing $U$ above is correct then it should also be positive semi-definite matrix. So perhaps a way to construct $U$ may be by applying Gram-Schmidt process and finding new eigenvectors for W.

Comment: There is something I am missing here. If $p\neq n$, the product $UV$ is not square, so it certainly cannot be symmetric positive definite.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I believe a non-square matrix can be symmetric semi-positive definite.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I am looking to try find an appropriate example for my claim. I think covariance matrices fit this category.

Comment: No, a non-square matrix cannot be symmetric positive definite. Either property separately implies the matrix is square.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I could be wrong but i would like to clarify here. Firstly I am interested in semi-Positive definite matrices not strictly positive definite. Secondly it is well known condition that covariance matrices must be semi-positive definite matrices. As they are allowed to be non square i can only conclude from this that it is possible to have non-square semi-positive definite matrices. If i am in correct in my understanding then please elaborate why this is not possible.

Comment: @MichaelGrant The discussion about this does make me suspect that $W$ may not be symmetric if it is non-square.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. I cannot be more certain that positive semidefinite matrices must be square. They need not be symmetric, but they must be square. This follows from the fundamental definition of positive semidefiniteness: a matrix $P$ is PSD if and only if $v^HPv\geq 0$ for all vectors $v$. This necessarily requires $P$ to be square, otherwise the multiplication would be ill-posed. In fact, I am also surprised by your claim that covariance matrices need not be square; I do not believe that to be correct, either. I welcome any references to the contrary.

Comment: Wait, are you talking about *cross-covariance* matrices? Those need not be square, for sure. But they are also not positive semidefinite.

Comment: I think there is some confusion about the definition of positive semidefinite matrices specially in case of real matrices. I was under the assumption a better definition of positive semi definite matrix is that all eigenvalues are greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: I think i am hoping for W to be a cross-covariance matrix. I never knew there was a special name for it. Thank you for pointing this out.

Comment: @MichaelGrant I wanted to thank you for your kindness and for taking an interest in my question. I have learned from this exchange. I am currently trying to dig up on if the two definitions of postive semidefinite matrices have the same or different implications. If they turn up to be the same then i would assume my hypothesis is ill-formed, unless p = n, as you have suggested.

Comment: For *symmetric* positive semidefinite matrices, the eigenvalues are all nonnegative. So yes, there is that alternate definition: a matrix $P$ is PSD if and only if the eigenvalues of $P+P^H$ are all nonnegative. But again, this definition applies only to square matrices---indeed, eigenvalues exist only for square matrices!

Comment: I'm glad we could get somewhere. It looks like indeed you may be referring to cross-covariance matrices. Unlike covariance matrices, which must be positive semidefinite, there is to my knowledge no similar condition on cross-covariance matrices.

Comment: @MichaelGrant Wow i was not aware that eigenvalues only existed for square matrices. So would it be correct to conclude then that i could pick any $n \times n$ square psd matrix for $U$ use it as multiple on the left side of $V$ to get a value for $W$ which would be psd as desired. ofcourse both $V$ and $W$ are also $n \times n$ matrices.

Comment: My suspicion is that that would be a sufficient condition, but not a necessary one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unsure how we should properly resolve this question.

As we have discussed at length in the comments, only square matrices can be positive semidefinite. Therefore, if $p\neq n$, there is no way that the product matrix $W=UV$ can be positive semidefinite, because it will also be non-square.

For grins, let's assume that $p=n$. Under what conditions is $W=UV$ positive semidefinite? This requires that $x^HUVx\geq 0$ for all complex vectors $x$. Alternatively, this is true if and only if $UV+VU^H=Q$ where $Q=W+W^H$ has nonnegative eigenvalues (and is therefore PSD itself). If $U$, $V$ are real, then you can relax the Hermitian transposes to real tranposes, and consider only reall vectors $x$.

Now for one special case, I know the answer. If $V$ is positive *definite*---i.e., not just PSD but nonsingular---and we require $W$ to be positive definite as well, then the answer follows from Lyapunov's theorem applied to linear systems:

- *The eigenvalues of $U$ must have positive real part.*

What about the more relaxed cases? That is, what if $V$ is only positive semidefinite? What if $W$ is only required to be positive semidefinite? I am afraid I do not know. I'm sure people who study Lyapunov's theorem for linear systems in some depth know...